# Using Adblock Plus subscriptions to remove ads from downloaded pages

Tags: screen-scraping, ads, adblock

I'd like to use the adblosck plus subscriptions to remove ads from the pages I'm about to scrap. Have anyone used such approach? What is the performance of such solution? What is the algorithm used by the extension itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling I've found the post by the extension author:
http://adblockplus.org/blog/investigating-filter-matching-algorithms

Answer (score 0):

Faster matching algorithm for ABP: https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6118